# Does the command "expectation" in Distributions.jl not work recently?

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

I tried the following commands

```
using DiffEqUncertainty, Distributions
expectation(g, prob, u0_dist, p)
```

Of course, the second command is not correct and many arguments are still missing, but it still serves for the purpose of nWME (not Working Minimal Example).

The error message I received is "**ERROR: UndefVarError: expectation not defined**". Am I missing some other packages to run "expectation" command?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DiffEqUncertainty` exports `expectation`, so it should be defined:

https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqUncertainty.jl/blob/master/src/DiffEqUncertainty.jl

In general when this error occurs despite things being exported by a package it is down to one of two issues:

1. An outdated package version, which does not export the same functions; or
2. A name clash, i.e. another package exporting a function with the same name - in this case you should get a warning, and qualifying the function (i.e. `DiffEqUncertainty.expectation`) should get around the issue.

Comment: Thank you @NilsGudat for your answer. For the first issue that you mentioned, I checked with ```] st``` and found that the version of DiffEqUncertainty.jl package is v1.2.0 and that of Distributions.jl package is 0.25.62. I am using Julia (version 1.7.3, on Windows 11, installed through Microsoft Store). For the second issue, there is no warning about name clash. However, I already tried with ```DiffEqUncertainty.expectation(...)```, but it still failed to run.

Comment: I see that the newest version of DiffEqUncertainty.jl package is 1.8.0. I tried to update the installed package by ```] up```, but it could not update the package to version 1.8.0. What can I do to update the package?

Comment: I finally can update the DiffEqUncertainty.jl package [by using ```] up DiffEqUnertainty@1.8.0```, now the command "expectation" works as expected.

Comment: What you're seing is likely incompatibilities between packages in your environment - this issue is much more likely if you are working in the default environment (`(@v1.7)` at the pkg prompt). It is highly recommended to work in project specific environments instead, with fewer packages installed. Also, Julia 1.8 will have an updated `]st` output which will highlight outdated packages to make identifying this issue easier.